# How to cross compile GCC with armv7 target?

Tags: ios, gcc, arm, fortran, cross-compiling

I try to cross compile **GCC 4.7.1** according to [this](http://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/07/21/compiling-gcc-4-7-1-mac-osx-lion/) tutorial. The only difference is, that I set as target architecture **arm-elf**, because I want to compile some **fortran** code to use it in our **iOS** App. But compilation just doesn't work. Does anyone have any suggestion?

```
../configure --prefix=/usr/gcc-4.7.1 --enable-checking=release --with-gmp=/usr/gcc-4.7.1 --with-mpfr=/usr/gcc-4.7.1 --with-mpc=/usr/gcc-4.7.1 --with-ppl=/usr/gcc-4.7.1 --with-cloog=/usr/gcc-4.7.1 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --program-suffix=-4.7 **--target=arm-elf**
```

After **make** I get these is the last lines in Terminal:

```
checking for arm-elf-gcc... /Users/xyz/Downloads/gcc-4.7.2/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/Users/xyz/Downloads/gcc-4.7.2/build/./gcc/ -B/usr/gcc-4.7.1/arm-elf/bin/ -B/usr/gcc-4.7.1/arm-elf/lib/ -isystem /usr/gcc-4.7.1/arm-elf/include -isystem /usr/gcc-4.7.1/arm-elf/sys-include   
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/Users/xyz/Downloads/gcc-4.7.2/build/arm-elf/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
```

Comment: Bit of a guess but I've seen similar problems when using --prefix and --with-gmp etc. solved by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the appropriate place. Only prob is mine wasn't a cross compile, and so my little brain is not quite sure what the appropriate place should be here!

Comment: Mac OS X and its mobile sibling iOS do not use ELF but rather Mach-O. Probably you should go with LLVM instead - check [this wiki](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev/wiki/Building).